# Apache Spark Streaming - graceful shutdown when stream has no more data

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am working on Spark Streaming API and I wish to stream a set of pre-downloaded web log files continuously to simulate a real-time stream. I wrote a script that gunzips the compressed logs and pipes the output to nc on port 7777.

The script looks like this:

```sh
BASEDIR=/home/mysuer/data/datamining/internet_traffic_archive
zipped_files=`find $BASEDIR -name "*.gz"`

for zfile in $zipped_files
 do
  echo "Unzipping $zfile..."
  gunzip -c $zfile  | nc -l -p 7777 -q 20

 done
```

I have streaming code written in Scala that processes the streams. It works well for the most part, but when its run out of files to stream it seems I get the following error:

```
16/02/19 23:04:35 WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: 
Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Socket data stream had no more data
16/02/19 23:04:35 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: 
Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Socket data stream had no more data
16/02/19 23:04:35 WARN BlockManager: Block input-0-1455941075600 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
....
16/02/19 23:04:40 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 47)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313)
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:311)
at com.femibyte.learningsparkaddexamples.scala.StreamingLogEnhanced$$anonfun$2.apply(StreamingLogEnhanced.scala:42)
at com.femibyte.learningsparkaddexamples.scala.StreamingLogEnhanced$$anonfun$2.apply(StreamingLogEnhanced.scala:42)
```

How to I implement a graceful shutdown so that the program exits gracefully when it no longer detects any data in the stream ?

My scala code looks like this:

```scala
object StreamingLogEnhanced {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val master = args(0)
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(master).setAppName("StreamingLogEnhanced")
    // Create a StreamingContext with a n second batch size
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
    // Create a DStream from all the input on port 7777
    val log = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)

    sys.ShutdownHookThread {
      log.info("Gracefully stopping Spark Streaming Application")
      ssc.stop(true, true)
      log.info("Application stopped")
    }
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 7777)
    // Create a count of log hits by ip
    var ipCounts=countByIp(lines)
    ipCounts.print()

    // start our streaming context and wait for it to "finish"
    ssc.start()
    // Wait for 600 seconds then exit
    ssc.awaitTermination(10000*600)
    ssc.stop()
  }

  def countByIp(lines: DStream[String]) = {
    val parser = new AccessLogParser
    val accessLogDStream = lines.map(line => parser.parseRecord(line))
    val ipDStream = accessLogDStream.map(entry => (entry.get.clientIpAddress, 1))
    ipDStream.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you are facing exception when your script is iterating over loop and spark tries to read data from socket and it is not available.

Comment: Can you share the Scala code? Specifically around `StreamingLogEnhanced.scala:42`? Looks like the last error is caused by your code calling `get` on a `None` object, but I really can't tell without seeing the code.

Comment: I wonder if the unzipping of files process takes time to decompress the file and suddenly makes the socket data inconsistent ...meaning no data at this moment in the socket stream? BTW ... I think this is 6000 secs ...  
`ssc.awaitTermination(10000*600)`.